# Iterate list of lists and finding consecutive numbers in those lists

Tags: python, list, nested

currently I am trying to find consecutive numbers in a nested list. My goal is the following example:

```
nested = [ [1,7,13], [2,5,8], [3, 6, 9] ]
```

OUTPUT : `(1,2,3), (7,8,9)`

It should also work if there are more than three lists. The amount of lists can vary.

(Background for this; i am building a search engine for school and the numbers in nested are positions of the query words given by a user.)

I have used :

```
def is_coherent(x):
    return all(np.diff(x) == 1)
```

to see if integers are consecutive. Also i have experimented with itertools.izip. However this does not allow me to change in the amount of lists i would like to iterate through.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is ur output correct ?

Comment: Why/how is `(7,8,9)` output from that?

Comment: its my desired output, excuse me =) I want to find consecutive numbers in multiple lists. In list 1 i find 7, in 2: 8 and in 3: 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to get those items from cartesian product of the inner lists whose all items are continuous, for that you can try something like this:

```
from itertools import izip, product

def find_continuous_items(data):
    for p in product(*data):
        if all(b-a==1 for a, b in izip(p, p[1:])):
            yield p

nested = [[1,7,13], [2,5,8], [3, 6, 9]]
print list(find_continuous_items(nested))
#[(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]
```